# Is is possible to use array_map in this case instead of foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following foreach statement:

```
$classes = '';

foreach($uriSet as $uri) {
   if (request()->is($uri)) {
      $classes .= 'active';
   }
}
```

Instead, I tried to use array map like so:

```
if (array_map([$this, 'checkUri'], $uriSet)) {
    $classes .= 'active';
}


// Somewhere down the class I have
public function checkUri($uri)
{
    return request()->is($uri);
}
```

but that if statement seems to be `true` all the time. I want to extract that into a separate method, as I will be using the `checkUri` method somewhere else in the same manner, but doing a different operation afterwards (not setting a classname like I have here).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with array_filter instead, like so:

```
if (array_filter($uriSet, [$this, 'checkUri'])) {
    $classes .= 'active';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_map()` returns an array, so your `if` statement will be `false` only if it will return an empty array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

> `array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )`
>   array_map() returns an array containing all the elements of array1
>   after applying the callback function to each one. The number of
>   parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number
>   of arrays passed to the array_map()

```
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Laravel, you can utilize the `contains` method on the `Collection` class:

```php
if (collect($uriSet)->contains([$this, 'checkUri'])) {
    $classes .= 'active';
}
```